# GridView_RowDeleting is not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, delete-row

Currently I am making a webapp in asp.net. Normally I use a sqlDataSource and enable paging and deleting etc, but I am not able to do that in this case.

I made a GridView and it shows the data perfectly, how ever my RowDelete event doesn't fire

**Code GridView:** ( only relevant code )

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server" 
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">

    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField 
         HeaderStyle-CssClass="head"
         ItemStyle-CssClass="items"
         HeaderText="Klant">

         <ControlStyle ForeColor="#333333" />
         <HeaderStyle CssClass="head"></HeaderStyle>
         <ItemStyle CssClass="items" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#494C50" ></ItemStyle>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="klant" runat="server"
              Text='<%#Eval("Bedrijf") %>'
              PostBackUrl='<%# "klant_wijzigen.aspx?Klant_ID="+Eval("Klant_ID").ToString()%>'></asp:LinkButton>
         </ItemTemplate>

      </asp:TemplateField>            

<asp:TemplateField 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="head"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="items"
    HeaderText="Categorie">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="categorie" runat="server"
        Text='<%#Eval("Categorie") %>'
        PostBackUrl='<%# "cat_wijzigen.aspx?Cat_ID="+Eval("Cat_ID").ToString()%>'>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <ControlStyle ForeColor="#333333" />

<HeaderStyle CssClass="head"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle CssClass="items" Font-Bold="false" ></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:BoundField 
    DataField="Website"
    headertext="Website"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="head"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="items">
<HeaderStyle CssClass="head"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle CssClass="items"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>


<asp:BoundField 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="head"
    DataField="Titel"
    headertext="Titel" 
    ItemStyle-CssClass="items"            
>
<HeaderStyle CssClass="head"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle CssClass="items"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="head2"
    ItemStyle-CssClass="items2">
    <ItemTemplate>


        <asp:Button ID="LinkButton1" 
            runat="server"                                         
            CausesValidation="False" 
            CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
            CssClass="verwijder"
            OnClientClick="return confirm
            ('Weet je zeker dat je het project wilt verwijderen?')">
        </asp:Button>

        <asp:Button ID="project" runat="server" 
            Text="Details"
            CssClass="details"
            PostBackUrl='<%#"Details.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID").ToString()%>' 
        />


    </ItemTemplate>

<HeaderStyle CssClass="head2"></HeaderStyle>

<ItemStyle CssClass="items2"></ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

<HeaderStyle CssClass="head"></HeaderStyle>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#e1e3e9" />
</asp:GridView>
```

As you can see they are all bounded. The delete button is a LinkButtton

And this is my script:

```
Protected Sub Gridview1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    GridView1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex)
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I bind my GridView like this: I have made 2 seperate SqlDataSources with 2 different Select Queries. Based on on the SelectedValue of my dropdownlist selects the SqlDataSource:

**Code**

```
Public Sub Wop() 'Here I set the IF statement.
    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = 0 Then
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource4()
    Else
        GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2()
    End If
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub


Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     
    Wop() `Here is were I call the IF statement.
End Sub
```

Any clue would be appreciated.

NOTE
I must say I am not writing in C#!

Comment: Will you post the rest of your `GridView` so we can see what the template actually looks like?  The way you have defined your rows and their delete buttons is also relevant information.

Comment: @MikeC I have added the whole GridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look like you're calling `DeleteRow` from within your `RowDeleting` event.  That doesn't make any sense since I would imagine that `RowDeleting` is not raised until `DeleteRow` is called.

**Edit:**

From MSDN:

> Use the DeleteRow method to programmatically delete the record at the
>   specified index from the data source. This method is commonly used
>   when you need to delete a record from outside of the GridView control,
>   such as from a different control on the page. **Calling this method also
>   raises the RowDeleted and RowDeleting events**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow.aspx

Comment: Mhh I couldnt find anythign like that in my book. Gonna check it out, Would love to upvote but I am not able to do that yet.